# Significant benefits of using bytes literal in python

Tags: python, string, byte, literals

After reading some articles, I know that string literal involves encoding and decoding.
Other than that, any other **practical benefits** of using byte literal b'....' in python.

```
# initialising a String 
a = 'abc'
  
# initialising a byte object
c = b'abc'
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're calling a function that needs a bytes argument, it's simpler to use a bytes literal instead of using a string and calling `.encode()`.

Comment: it's the same reason you use an integer literal instead of writing `int("123")`

Comment: With escapes you can actually use byte array literals with any value. Those would be stored as actual bytes rather than as a string - which would then need to be encoded. Note that not all bytes need to be covered by an encoding, encoding mistakes are easy to make. If you would store a string a hex (or base 64 string) would be preferable, but in that case you could also simply escape each and every byte in the b-string.

Answer (score 0):

Internet sockets, which allow transfer of data between programs on the internet, can only handle sequences of bytes.

So in order for your python program to send data to other programs on the internet via an internet socket connection, the data must first be encoded into a bytes literal.

Likewise, data sent into your python program via an internet socket connection always comes in the form of an encoded bytes literal that has to be decoded into a regular python string before use.